# Getting the XPATH for calendar in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I'm having some trouble accessing a calendar date on a website. This is the HTML code and I want to access the 3rd day of September.

```
<tbody><tr><td class="dayHeader">S</td><td class="dayHeader">M</td><td class="dayHeader">T</td><td class="dayHeader">W</td><td class="dayHeader">T</td><td class="dayHeader">F</td><td class="dayHeader">S</td></tr><tr><td class="dayHeader" colspan="7"><b>September 2023</b></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="dayCell dayPast " onclick="" style=""><div name="cellDiv" id="day1690848000" class="">1</div></td><td class="dayCell dayPast " onclick="" style=""><div name="cellDiv" id="day1690934400" class="">2</div></td><td class="dayCell dayPast " onclick="" style=""><div name="cellDiv" id="day1691020800" class="">3</div></td><td class="dayCell dayPast " onclick="" style=""><div name="cellDiv" id="day1691107200" class="">4</div></td></tr>
```

The days are text elements that I am using `text()='3'` with 3 as a variable to access, however, I want this to be as flexible as possible so that if I need access to the next month I could just have a variable for the month. The month name is also a text element and I am accessing it using text() as well also with a variable for the month.

I have tried these lines of code and it works for the month of August(the default month in the calendar), however, when I plug in September it thinks that it is August and selects that day in August for example 3rd of September would select the 3rd of August. I think what's happening is that it is defaulting to the August calendar and not going to the September calendar.

```
test = f'{calendar.month_name[selectMonth]} {dt_now.year}'
calendarMonth = wb.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//b[text()='{test}']")
calendarDay = calendarMonth .find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[text()='{selectDay}']").click()
```

So what I want is an XPATH code that has the month and day in one line. I have also tried the following code but it is not a correct xpath code.

```
test = f'{calendar.month_name[selectMonth]} {dt_now.year}'
//b[text()='{test}']//div[text()='{selectDay}']
```

Thanks!

Comment: solved: this was the solution `calanderMonth = wb.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@class='calendarTable' and contains(.,'{test}')]//div[text()='{selectDay}']").click()`